# Can't open or find downloaded mp3 file

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am downloading audio file in mp3 and trying to play it with a music player but can't find the mp3 file anywhere. I can only see it from my app. No music player apps can access it.
Here is the code.

```
Future<String?> saveAudio(bytes, fileName) async {
        Directory directory;
        try {
          directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;
          if (await directory.exists()) {
            final saveFile = File('${directory.path}/$fileName.mp3');
            await saveFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);
            return saveFile.absolute.path;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
              .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("An error occurred")));
        }
        return null;
      }
downloadFile(bytes, fileName) async {
    String? downloadedPath = await saveAudio(bytes, fileName);
    if (downloadedPath == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("An error occurred")));
    } else {
      if (downloadedPath.isNotEmpty) {
        AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
            action: 'action_view',
            data: Uri.encodeFull(downloadedPath),
            type: "audio/*");
        await intent.launch();
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("An error occurred")));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does it work with getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() instead?

Comment: @activout.se no it's not working